# CRLF causing problems in finding an element via xpath

Tags: xpath

I am working on a test case and need to find text within a table.  The only thing to key off of is the label in the previous column.  The keys are Next Trckng/Dschrg, Next Full, Next Qtrly, Next Mdcr.  I would like to create an xpath expression that will find the Text 1, Text 2, Text 3, and Text 4 based on the key.  Since all the keys have the word Next in them, I have mocked this up to find all four of them at once.

//td[preceding-sibling::td[contains(descendant::text(),'Next')]]/a

The third one is not found because it does not have an 'a' element, which is fine.  the problem comes in the very first td.  It has a span in it, unlike the others.  The span is on a second physical line from the td.  It appears that the CRLF is preventing FirePath from finding the first td, when I put the span on the same line as the td, it is found.  The problem is that I cannot change the actual page, this is a test case.

Is this a FireBug issue or is this actually resulting in two text elements in the DOM?  How do I tweak the xpath to find all four nodes?

Here is the HTML:

```
<table border=1>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id="xxx"><a><img></a></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Next Trckng/Dschrg:</td>
            <td><a>Text 1</a></td>
            <td>Next Full:</td>
            <td><a>Text 2</a></td>
            <td>Next Qtrly:</td>
            <td>&nbsp;<!-- Text 3 --></td>
            <td>Next Mdcr:</td>
            <td><a>Text 4</a></td>
            <td>Change Of Therapy:</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the expression `contains(descendant::text(),'Next')`. The `contains` function takes two strings as arguments. Since you pass a node-set as first argument, it is converted to a string. The conversion works by calling the `string` function on the node-set which [according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions) returns the string-value of the node that is *first* in document order. In your case, this will be the first text child of a `td` element. For the first `td` element, this is a text node containing only whitespace.

The solution is simple: Pass the current `td` element to the `contains` function:

```
contains(., 'Next')
```

The string-value of this single node will contain the [concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#element-nodes).